# AngularJs ng-click VS jquery on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to angular and failing to understand why should i use angular `ng-click` over jQuery event listeners? Since the best practice is to use only one of them in my App (according to [this highly up voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)) Isn't there any elegant solution in angular to listen to events such as in jquery?

**jQuery**

```
<span>Box 1</span>
<span>Box 2</span>
<span>Box 3</span>

$("span").on('click',function() {
  // do something 
});
```

**Angular**

```
<span ng-click="doSomething();">Box 1</span>
<span ng-click="doSomething();">Box 2</span>
<span ng-click="doSomething();">Box 3</span>

$scope.doSomething = function(){
    // do something
};
```

What will happen if i'll need to change the function name, or remove it completely, in angular i'll have to go over the entire code and remove the ng-clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason not to use jQuery is that in that case the click handler will not trigger a digest in angular (no dirty checking will be done, no watches will fire, nothing will be updated).

IMHO the occasional ng-click is fine, but if you need the same structure repeatedly, you should write a directive, so that you can say something like:

```
<box box-data="{{myModel.subModel}}"></box>
```

That way you would also not need to worry so much about keeping html and js in sync when refactoring - everything is neatly encapsulated in the directive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-repeat

In JS

```
$scope.spans = ["Box 1", "Box 2", "Box 3"]
```

In HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="s in spans" ng-click="doSomething()">{{s}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to rewrite your code or leave the "hg-click="doSomething();" parts and just change the doSomething function as // do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you should use jQuery code in an AngularJS application is in a custom directive (it's a best practice).

So, if you really want to clean up your spans tags, you have to create a custom directive englobing all your spans with a link function containing your aforementioned jQuery code, BUT it may not be very practical nor a good idea.

The best way is to stick to AngularJS directives like ng-click for something as simple as to react to a click event, to have less unpredictable behaviors.